# <li> arranged horizontally issue

Tags: html, html-lists

```
//for submenu
DataTable subcate = new BALCate().GetSubCate(cateid);
if (subcate.Rowsount > 0)
{
    div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    div.Attributes.Add("class", "sub-menu");
    HtmlGenericControl sul = new HtmlGenericControl("sul");

    foreach (DataRow sdr in subcate.Rows)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl sli = new HtmlGenericControl("sli");
        HtmlAnchor slink = new HtmlAnchor();
        slink.HRef = "#";
        slink.InnerHtml = sdr["subcate_name"].ToString();
        sli.Controls.Add(slink);
        sul.Controls.Add(sli);
    }
    div.Controls.Add(sul);
    li.Controls.Add(div);
 }
nav.Controls.Add(li);
```

.aspx

```
<div class="categories">
<ul runat="server" id="nav">
<li class="home" style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-color: #6FA907; background-image: url(home.jpg); background-position: center;"><a href="index.htm">Home</a></li>
<!--Dynamic menu-->
</ul>
</div>
```

**please arrange this these li s vertically**

can any one solve this error --- explained below

could `<li> </li>` tags within `<ul> </ul>` tag be in vertical manner ??? if yes then please tell me  thnk u

Answer (score 0):

```
// CSS
li { display : block; }
```

Except that vertically is the default for `li` elements, unless you've unset that somewhere else in your CSS, already.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make it as `display: block;` or `display: list-item;`, which is the default.

So, your CSS would be:

```
#nav li {display: block;}
```

Or

```
#nav li {display: list-item;}
```

Check out both and use the one which suits. :)